# SVG Grid lines are Blurred in Google Chrome while zooming but its work fine in Mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1300" height="900" viewBox="0 0 750 300" id="mainsvg">

    <g>
        <defs>
            <pattern x="0" y="0" width="1.6" id="smallGrid" height="1.6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" id="smallgridbox" fill="none" stroke="rgb(8,24,77)" stroke-width="1"></path>
            </pattern>
            <pattern width="16" id="grid" height="16" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="687.47" y="0" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
                <rect fill="url(#smallGrid)" width="16" height="16" fill-opacity="0.5"></rect>
                <path d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100" id="largegridbox" fill="none" stroke="rgb(8,24,77)" stroke-width="1"></path>
            </pattern>
        </defs>

        <rect fill="url(#grid)" width="1375" height="773" x="0" y="0" fill-opacity="0.5"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KashifMKH/L46j18fo/6/

It works fine in Mozilla Firefox, but not in Chrome. Zoom it at large and then compare the results in Mozilla and Chrome: you will see the difference clearly. How can I fix it?

Comment: My suspicion would be that you are changing the viewBox parameters rather than the height and width parameters.  While the viewBox parameters can be changed, you will most likely have more success with just adjusting the height and width to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: @rfornal No, you would be shrinking / enlarging the SVG canvas by changing its 'width' & 'height' attributes. Viewbox is the way to go, however, Chrome does seem to be behaving strangely here...

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your fiddle in chromium. That the gridlines become blurry if one zoomes in, appears also to me.

So I »manually« changed the `viewBox` in the html code so that the svg is scaled initially. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L46j18fo/7/)

Result: No blurry Gridlines.

So I think it is quiet obvious that chrom - e/ium does not rerender the pattern if the viewBox changes. You could try to update the `viewBox` by using the direct DOM-Binding:

```
var  vb = a.viewBox.baseVal;
vb.x = ...
vb.y = ...
```

If that does not work I would try to use transforms and if that does not work, I think you cannot use `<pattern>` to create the grid and `<use>` elements, created by Javascript are the next option.